# complex mysql joined query

Tags: mysql

i have two tables. disease and doctor. disease to doctor 1 to many relationship.

when i search with a keyword that will match all disease and doctors name and show the resulted data. suppose i wrote "Karim". this will mach disease names from disease table and doctors name from doctors table. and where it finds a correct match, it will select the row.

I am not undersanding how to write this query. I can do this for only 1 table. here is my code:

```
$query = "select * from disease where diseasename = '".$txtSearch."'";
$query = "select * from doctor where doctorname = '".$txtSearch."'";
```

but plz anyone can say me how to join this two query?

Comment: What what kind of result you want to achieve? How helpful can be result set with mixed up diseases and doctors? PS: this question is not complex and isn't about joins

Comment: What do these tables look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `OR` keyword.
Try :

```
$query = "select * from disease dis inner join doctor doc on dis.doctor_id = doc.id where (dis.diseasename = '".$txtSearch."' or doc.doctorname = '".$txtSearch."')";
```

I have made some assumptions on the column names since you haven't posted them in your question. You will have to replace them with the appropriate ones from your database.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I should have used the inner keyword. Been writing too much HQL these days.

Comment: thnks @jeshurun. my purpose fulfilled.

Comment: @zerkms Still not sure what you mean. `on dis.doctor_id = doc.id` isn't this the join condition?

Comment: @jeshurun: oh my god, I'm blind, sorry